# Android call non-static Java method from Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to call a non-static Java method from a Kotlin file as I need to be able to use findViewById. However When I changed my method to non-static the Kotlin file returned the following error: Unresolved reference: main. When the Java method was static the Kotlin file was able to run the Java method.

> Kotlin File:

```
class RoundFactoryImpl(private val randomiser: Randomiser) : RoundFactory {
     override fun buildRound(cards: List<Card>): Round = Round()
     val card = Round()
     val customer = PokemonRand.main(randomiser, card)
}
```

> Java File:

```java
public void main(Randomiser randomiser, Round cards) {
    Card cardA, cardB;

    cardA = getCard(randomiser, cards);
    cardB = getCard(randomiser, cards);

    Log.d("cardA", cardA.toString());
    Log.d("cardB", cardB.toString());

    while (cardA.getRarity() == cardB.getRarity()) {
        cardB = getCard(randomiser, cards);
    }

    dispCard(cardA, cardB);
    compCard(cardA, cardB);
}
```

Comment: You would need an instance of the PokemonRand class to be able to call an instance method on it. But I think there are some more fundamental design issues going on here. This function named `main` (which really should have a name describing what it does) doesn't return anything. It is basically a function that takes a deck of cards and I guess displays two of them to a user. So why is something that's called a Factory telling some other object to pick and display two cards when the Factory is instantiated, and then storing `Unit` in a property called `customer`? None of that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
val customer = PokemonRand.main(randomiser, card)
```

First issue with your code is you are assigning the value of your `main` method to `customer` variable whose return type is `void`;

Second problem with the code is your main method is not static so you need to create an instance of the `PokemonRand` class and call the `main` method on that instance like the following

```
val pokemon = PokemonRand();
pokemon.main(randomiser, card);
```

Comment: I changed it to what you wrote but I'm getting an error on the line pokemon.main(randomiser, card); which is saying expecting member declaration

Comment: If the PokemonRand is the view controller (Activity or Fragment), it doesn't make sense to instantiate one to call this method.

Comment: @Imstuck can you please post the full code of `PokemonRand` class